# How to invert the selection in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

To test that a web form keeps the selected elements when submission fails, I'd like to invert the selection of a multi-select element (without knowing beforehand what the selection was), store that selection, `clickAndWait` the `submit` button and `assert` that the selection is unchanged. `select` doesn't seem to support a value like `xpath=//option[(not(@selected))]`, so is there some easy way to do this? My first idea would be to do something like this:

```
addSelection | element | *
removeSelection | element | @selected
storeSelected | element | selectedElements
```

Unfortunately the `*select*` commands all seem to only work with a single element, and don't support XPath, so it's not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you meant exactly this, but:

in web form placed on site: http://www.poradnik-webmastera.com/kursy/html/formularze.php

this code worked for me:

```
addSelection | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4] | label=Polski
addSelection | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4] | label=Niemiecki
storeSelectedLabels | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4] | selected
//clicking SUBMIT button
verifySelectedLabels | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4] | ${selected}
```

Assuming that all addSelections are random, "storeSelectedLabels" will store all selections then goes imaginary action of clicking submit button and then is verification (or assertion) of selections.

Comment: I don't understand - How is adding two selections supposed to *invert* the current selection?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. I didn't get your point, sorry.

Anyway, if I wanted to invert selection of multi-select element I'll do it like this (concerning this 3-element dropdown on page I provided before):

```
storeSelectedIndexes | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4] | selected
removeAllSelections | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4]
store | ${selected} | selected2
store | javascript{storedVars['selected2'].split(',').length} | selectedNo
store | 999 | selectedIndexNo0
store | 999 | selectedIndexNo1
store | 999 | selectedIndexNo2
store | -1 | loop1
while | ${loop1} < (${selectedNo} - 1)
store | javascript{storedVars.loop1++}
store | javascript{storedVars['selected2'].split(',')[storedVars['loop1']]} | selectedIndexNo${loop1}
endWhile | 
store | -1 | loop2
while | ${loop2} < 2
store | javascript{storedVars.loop2++}
gotoIf | ${loop2} == ${selectedIndexNo0} || ${loop2} == ${selectedIndexNo1} || ${loop2} == ${selectedIndexNo2} | dontSelect
addSelection | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4] | index=${loop2}
label | dontSelect
endWhile |
```

It's not the easiest way, I suppose, but works.

It's suitable for three multi-select elements.

First loop (while - endWhile) extracts selected indexes and second loop selects all elements except those selected previously.

---

Ok, I made a few changes and this version of script is fine to use with any-size elements (as long as first label has index=0). All you have to do is put id or xpath for examined multiform in first command and provide number of all labels in element either by storeXpathCount or by simply putting a number of them. And add more/ less conditions to "gotoIf" command depending on size of multiform.

2nd version of script:

```
//store | put here id or xpath of your dropdown | elementID
store | xpath=(//select[@name='jezyk'])[4] | elementID
storeSelectedIndexes | ${elementID} | selected
removeAllSelections | ${elementID}
store | ${selected} | selected2
store | javascript{storedVars['selected2'].split(',').length} | selectedNo
//use custom xpath or explicitly type number of labels using simple "store" command instead of "storeXpathCount"
storeXpathCount | //div[@id='content']/div/div[2]/div[31]/div/select/option | elementSize
store | -1 | loop0
while | ${loop0} < ${elementSize}
store | javascript{storedVars.loop0++}
store | 999 | selectedIndexNo${loop0}
endWhile | 
store | -1 | loop1
while | ${loop1} < (${selectedNo} - 1)
store | javascript{storedVars.loop1++}
store | javascript{storedVars['selected2'].split(',')[storedVars['loop1']]} | selectedIndexNo${loop1}
endWhile | 
store | -1 | loop2
while | ${loop2} < (${elementSize} - 1)
store | javascript{storedVars.loop2++}
//depending on size of your multiform element you have to add more conditions to below "gotoIf" command. At the moment it's good for three elements (labels)
gotoIf | ${loop2} == ${selectedIndexNo0} || ${loop2} == ${selectedIndexNo1} || ${loop2} == ${selectedIndexNo2} | dontSelect
addSelection | ${elementID} | index=${loop2}
label | dontSelect
endWhile |
```